# Autofac: generic class implementing a non generic interface not being injected

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

Say I have the following (simplified) object model:

> ```
> public abstract class Message
> {
> }
> public class SimpleMessage:Message
> {
> }
> public class ComplexMessage:Message
> {
> }
> public interface IMessageHandler{
>
>     void Handle(Message message);
> }
>
> public class NonGenericMessageHandler1: IMessageHandler{
>
>     void Handle(Message message){      
>       Console.WriteLine("hi dad!")
>     }
> }   
> public class NonGenericMessageHandler2: IMessageHandler{
>     void Handle(Message message){        
>       Console.WriteLine("hi mom!")
>     }
> }
> public class GenericMessageHandler<T> :IMessageHandler where T: Message>{ 
>     void Handle(Message message){
>         //do something cool with the generic
>     }
> }   
>
>  public class MessageHandlerFactory: IMessageHandlerFactory{
>     public MessageHandlerFactory(IEnumerable<IMessageHandler> handlers){
>     }
>     public IMessageHandler Create(Message message){
>          //return the right handler
>     }   
>  }
> ```

Here's the problem.  The `IEnumerable<IMessageHandler>` autofac injects into MessageHandlerFactory only contains the nongeneric implementations of `IMessageHandler`.
If I want the generic version, I have to declare the various closed versions manually, as follows:

> ```
>  public MessageHandlerFactory(IEnumerable<IMessageHandler> handlers, MessageHandler<SimpleMessage> handler1, MessageHandler<ComplexMessage> handler2){
>
>  }
> ```

Here's how I'm wiring up Autofac:

> ```
>   builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (IMessageHandlerFactory).Assembly)
>                  .AsImplementedInterfaces()
>                  .AsSelf()
>                  .SingleInstance();
>
>           builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (MessageHandler<>)).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
> ```

How can I get Autofac to pass in a unified collection of all `IMessageHandler` implementors, including any generic variants?

Comment: What do you mean with Autofac?

Comment: You should show the actual registration code you are trying to get working.

Comment: added Autofac registration code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I figured it out.  It boils down to a chicken or egg scenario.  When you register a generic class via the `RegisterGeneric` method, Autofac will **not** automatically register the closed types unless it detects them somewhere in your object graph as a dependency.

**Ctor 1** doesn't trigger closed generics to be registered:

> ```
>    public MessageHandlerFactory(IEnumerable<IMessageHandler> handlers){
>
>    }
> ```

**Ctor 2** does trigger closed generics to be registered:

```
   public MessageHandlerFactory(IEnumerable<IMessageHandler> handlers,
                                MessageHandler<ComplexMessage> complexHandler,
                                MessageHandler<SimpleMessage> simpleHandler
){}
```

Once I manually registered the closed generics using the code below, Autofac began injecting them as part of the `IEnumerable<IMessageHandler>` dependency seen on Ctor 1

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(MessageHandler<ComplexMessage>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();

builder.RegisterType(typeof(MessageHandler<SimpleMessage>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```